# Update CollectionViewSource When ObservableCollection Changes WP7

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone-7

I have an`ObservableCollection` for my underlying list of items. I have 2 `CollectionViewSource` that are different filters of the data. I want any changes that happen to be reflected in the `CollectionViewSource`.

In my view model constructor, I set the filter predicates. I then get the data an add it to the `ObservableCollection`. I am subscribed to the `CollectionChanged` event, and am refreshing the CVS there.

I am seeing some really weird things with this though. Either the items don't show up in my `ListBox` that is bound to the CVS, or duplicates will show up. If I call `Refresh` on the CVS outside of the `CollectionChanged` event after I change the `ObservableCollection`, everything seems to work fine. I would really like to be able to just refresh when the collection changes and not worry about having to call refresh every time something is done that changes it.

```
public MyViewModel()
{
    oc.CollectionChanged += OcCollectionChanged;

    cvs1.Source = oc;
    cvs1.View.Filter = new Predicate<object>( ... );

    cvs2.Source = oc;
    cvs2.View.Filter = new Predicate<object>( ... );

    foreach( var data in myData )
    {
        oc.Add( data );
    }
}

private void OcCollectionChanged( object sender, NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e )
{
    cvs1.View.Refresh();
    cvs2.View.Refresh();
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`CollectionViewSource` doesn't implement `INotifyPropertyChanged`, so to get any underlying data changes into the UI you need to call `Refresh` on the View as you are already doing. `CollectionViewSource` is also data source agnostic, so the fact that the source is an `ObservableCollection` that raises property change notification is immaterial, because the `CollectionViewSource` is not listening.

I think the solution you have of manually refreshing the views when the collection changes is the best you're going to get without re-thinking your data structures.

Comment: What I'm seeing is issues with putting the refresh in the `CollectionChanged` event. I don't see the issues if I call `Refresh` after I changed the collection. Is this a know problem or is there something I can do to fix this? I can call `Refresh` manually after I add/remove something from the `ObservableCollection`, but I don't see why it shouldn't work when calling it from the `CollectionChanged` event.

Answer (score 3):

I am using a modified `ObservableCollection` class that specifically overcomes the limitation mentioned above (`CollectionChangedEvent` event firing multiple times), found [here. (ObservableCollectionEx - blocks the CollectionChangedEvent until all are added by adding an AddRange method)](http://www.damonpayne.com/Permalink.aspx?title=AddRangeForObservableCollectionInSilverlight3&date=2010-03-04)

I've been using it for about 2 years now, and it works terrifically well for large collection changes.

**Update**:
It appears that link is down, so here's the code:

```
public class ObservableCollectionEx<T> : ObservableCollection<T>
{
    public ObservableCollectionEx()
        : base()
    {
        _suspendCollectionChangeNotification = false;
    }


    bool _suspendCollectionChangeNotification;

    protected override void OnCollectionChanged(NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if(!_suspendCollectionChangeNotification)
        {
            base.OnCollectionChanged(e);
        }
    }

    public void SuspendCollectionChangeNotification()
    {
        _suspendCollectionChangeNotification = true;
    }

    public void ResumeCollectionChangeNotification()
    {
        _suspendCollectionChangeNotification = false;
    }


    public void AddRange(IEnumerable<T> items)
    {
        this.SuspendCollectionChangeNotification();
        int index = base.Count;
        try
        {
            foreach(var i in items)
            {
                base.InsertItem(base.Count, i);
            }
        }
        finally
        {
            this.ResumeCollectionChangeNotification();
            var arg = new NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs(NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Reset);
            this.OnCollectionChanged(arg);
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `ObservableCollection` has its limitations.  Consider that loop you have in your code, how may times does it call the `Add` method?  How many times therefore will the changed event fire and how often will the refresh methods get called?  Its not too surprising that this code gets itself in a pickle when so many changes happen in quick succession.

The `ObservableCollection` is great when its initially loaded, then its change event is monitored and small relatively infrequent changes are made from that point.  For large scale changes its probably better to load an entirely new instance and then assign this new instance to a property.

Have the property setter re-assign the `Source` properties on the  `CollectionViewSource` objects.  If you still want to observe the collection you can detatch and attach your event handlers in the setter as well.